# Second instance of UIViewController instantiated, loosing initializations done on original. Why?

Tags: iphone

I'm having a problem with the following code. As you can a TripDetailsController is created (subclass of UIViewController) and this one is initialized with the initWithNibName method. This initWithNibName takes an extra argument (tripDetails), see code of TripDetailsController class below. The variable td has a value and when stepping through the code, I checked that this value was set on the tdController when the initWithNibName method is executed. However, when setting a breakpoint in the TripDetailsController.viewDidLoad method (which is executed when pushViewController() is called) the tripDetails attribute of the TripDetailsController is nil ?!?
Using the debugger I discovered that the tdController instance that I see in the initWithNibName method is a different instance than the instance that I see in the viewDidLoad method? How come? Why is there an new instance of the TripDetailsController created and by who?

At the end of this post I included a dump of call stack, maybe that give you a hint for the cause of this problem.

Code:

```
// Code from RootViewController.getTripDetails() (see stacktrace below)
TripDetails td = ...;   // td has a value
// Push the detail view controller
TripDetailsController *tdController = [[TripDetailsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TripDetailsController" bundle:nil tripDetails:td];

             // Checked using the debugger that tdController.tripDetails is set

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tdController animated:YES];
[tdController release];
```

Code:

```
@implementation TripDetailsController

@synthesize tripDetails, expectedDurationLabel, normalDurationLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationItem.title = @"Reis Details";  
  expectedDurationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tripDetails.expectedDuration];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle tripDetails:(TripDetails *)td {
  self = [self initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
  self.tripDetails = td;    // self.tripDetails has a value here!
  [self.tripDetails retain];
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [self.tripDetails release];
  [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

[alt text http://gerodt.homeip.net/stack.png](http://gerodt.homeip.net/stack.png)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Gero

Comment: While unrelated, you don't need to do [self.tripDetails retain] since, presumably, that property gets retained automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it working by following the sample code from the S[impleDrillDown example](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/index.html) from Apple.

Main differences with my original code:

- TripDetailsController is no longer defined in .xib file
- TripDetailsController no longer loaded from .xib file, but initialized as follows:

Code:

```
TripDetailsController *tdController = 
    [[TripDetailsController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

- TripDetailsController is no longer a UIViewController, but a subclass of UITableViewController

As a result I had to tweak the layout a bit, but at least it now works.

Looks as if it is not possible to initialize a view controller from a XIB file and then push it on to the navigation controller.

Gero

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not retaining tripDetails object, so it's getting released before you try to use.

Comment: I was already retaining the tripDetails object in initWithNibName method (see code above) and now also added a retain in the code where the tripDetails object is created. This had no effect.

I wonder if the problem is retainment of the tripDetails object itself, because the pointer value of the TripDetailsController instance is different in the viewDidLoad and the initWithNibName methods. I'm expecting that the problem lies in that area. Why are there two instances of the TripDetailsController? I only create one.

Comment: You don't need the retain since the property (presumably) retains it.  If it WERE getting released for some reason, you'd have an exception when you try to access a deallocated object instead of the ivar becoming nil.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code that calls `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

My hunch is that you're creating one programatically, but the one that's actually getting used is being created in a NIB file.  Maybe your main view NIB creates a TripDetailsController as a tab view or navigation root.  In that case, `initWithCoder:` gets called instead of `initWithNibName:bundle:`, which would explain the uninitialized `td` ivar.

Comment: The code that calls the initWithNameName:bundle:tripDetails is included above. It is the first code snippet. The rest of the code is the implementation of the TripDetailsController.

Comment: Second note: nitWithNameName:bundle:tripDetails does get invoked since  did set a breakpoint there and execution stopped there.

Comment: That is indeed very strange.  Looking at your code, I don't see how tdController in getTripDetails can be a different instance than the one that receives viewDidLoad.  The only thing I can think of is that the debugger is actually executing an older version of the code... I've had this happen when I changed the product ID of the build target.

Comment: With UIViewControllers, you sometimes get strange behavior if you don't use viewDidLoad for setup (or perform externally after the initialization). I edited my answer after remembering this. I guess this is why Apple tells you to use viewDidLoad for additional setup.

Comment: I added an explicit call to viewDidLoad() before doing the pushViewController and in that case that invocation of viewDidLoad is OK. However, the pushViewController also triggers a viewDidLoad and then the instance of TripDetailsController is different again (and the tripDetails property is nil)

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I have seen this before:

Instead of making a custom initializer, use the standard one and try this:

```
TripDetails td = ...;   // td has a value
TripDetailsController *tdController = [[TripDetailsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TripDetailsController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[tdController setTripDetails:td]

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tdController animated:YES];
[tdController release];
```

---

Original answer:
In the TripDetailsController interface, is the thipDetails property set to retain? (and not assign).

Comment: This was my original approach and has the same effect as the approach I listed in the original post. The pointer value of 'tdController' is different than the value of 'self' in the TripDetailsController.viewDidLoad method (and the tripDetails attribute is nil in viewDidLoad).

Yes, the tripDetails property is set to retain in the .h file.

Comment: Shouldn't matter with this class, but are you doing if(self=[super initWithNib:bundle:])? Weird that self isn't the same object. I would try rewriting this code in another project and see what happens. It sounds like you have some hard to track down bug.